# What does the error code "1000008e" mean?

Tags: windows, bsod

My computer keeps restarting and crashes with a blue screen. It gives me the following error code:

```
BCCode: 1000008e
BCP1: C0000005
BCP2: 9A245607
BCP3: AB3326EC
BCP4: 00000000
OS Version: 6_1_7601
Service Pack: 1_0
Product: 256_1
```

What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: Please update your question with details as to what sort of computer you have, what OS you're running, what things you're doing when the error occurs, and any other details that may help us get a clear picture of what is going on around and concerning the error.

Comment: It's obviously Windows 7 with service pack 1. The code, from what I've seen, seems to be unhandled exception caused by a kernel mode program. Could be possibly a bad driver or something similar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Filled out my answer as per the request.

> **Bug Check 0x1000008E: KERNEL_MODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED_M**
>
> Bug check 0x1000008E has the same meaning and parameters as bug check 0x8E (KERNEL_MODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED).

Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff557203(v=vs.85).aspx)

This blue screen can have several causes (from most likely to least likely):

- Faulty RAM
- Faulty hardware
- A problem with a device driver
- A virus

To help narrow down the cause, follow these steps:

1. Carry out some memory diagnostics using [Memtest](http://www.memtest86.com/).

   If any tests fail, replace the RAM and see if the blue screens persist.
2. Check to see if your RAM is properly seated in the motherboard.

   This one seems obvious but I felt I should put it here for completeness.  Whilst unlikely, it can be the cause of this error but unless you've opened the case recently or transported the PC anywhere, it's not likely to be the problem.
3. Have you changed the BIOS settings for your RAM?

   If you've overclocked your RAM or misconfigured the RAM settings, this is also a potential cause.  You can try restoring the default BIOS settings.
4. Disable RAM caching/shadowing settings in the BIOS

   Somewhat related to the last point, but you can try disabling these and see if it alleviates the problem.
5. Have you recently install new device drivers prior to receiving the blue screen?

   If so, uninstall the driver(s) and if possible, go back to older version(s).  Try the machine out and see if the blue screens persist.
6. Carry out a virus scan.

   This isn't likely to be the problem, but in very rare cases a virus can result in this blue screen.

Other things to try would be swapping out the graphics card, making sure your hardware is all compatible with the OS and also perhaps updating the BIOS.

Comment: Could you perhaps edit your answer to include some possible fixes?

Comment: @SimonSheehan Are you having issues viewing the link or is it because you'd prefer to have the information embedded directly here?  It's not a problem, just curious really.

Comment: We generally prefer the information be put here, to prevent links rotting and dying.

Comment: @SimonSheehan Yeah that's a fair point.  I'll edit my answer and add the appropriate information from the thread.

Comment: @SimonSheehan Updated as requested.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely to caused by memory errors. Make a [memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org) boot CD and boot from it. Let the test run for a few hours. One error is too many.

If you get any memory errors, the problem is either hardware or BIOS settings. The first thing to try is changing all BIOS memory voltages and timings back to their defaults and re-testing.

If you get no memory errors, I'd suspect a driver issue. Most likely the graphics card driver.