# Windows XP only loads in VGA mode, and crashes when raising resolution

Tags: windows-xp, crash, display

My kid's computer (Windows XP, SP3) started to (what appears to be) crash on boot. 
It will only boot in Safe or VGA mode, and if I try to raise the resolution from 640x480 it just reboots itself, and a error appears in the Event Log. 
When it loads up not in VGA mode, the monitor shuts off just after the windows logo is shown. It seems like windows is actually running but I can't see anything on screen (monitor is off for lack of signal).

Nothing was installed recently that I know of, short of the usual windows updates.

Thanks,
Harel

Below is the event log error:

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source:   System Error
Event Category: (102)
Event ID:   1003
Date:       15/04/2012
Time:       16:27:11
User:       N/A
Computer:   -----
Description:
Error code 1000008e, parameter1 c0000005, parameter2 f745b0bf, parameter3 ede24f98, parameter4 00000000.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
Data:
0000: 53 79 73 74 65 6d 20 45   System E
0008: 72 72 6f 72 20 20 45 72   rror  Er
0010: 72 6f 72 20 63 6f 64 65   ror code
0018: 20 31 30 30 30 30 30 38    1000008
0020: 65 20 20 50 61 72 61 6d   e  Param
0028: 65 74 65 72 73 20 63 30   eters c0
0030: 30 30 30 30 30 35 2c 20   000005, 
0038: 66 37 34 35 62 30 62 66   f745b0bf
0040: 2c 20 65 64 65 32 34 66   , ede24f
0048: 39 38 2c 20 30 30 30 30   98, 0000
0050: 30 30 30 30               0000
```

Comment: You'r question is pretty vague.  Have you scanned for Malware?  Have you tried updating/reinstalling drivers?  Have you tried a System Restore to a point before it was being problematic?

Comment: Have you checked out these: [What does the error code “1000008e” mean?](http://superuser.com/questions/361441/what-does-the-error-code-1000008e-mean), [System randomly Crashing](http://superuser.com/questions/248754/system-randomly-crashing), [How do I troubleshoot problems that occur during boot?](http://superuser.com/questions/230748/how-do-i-troubleshoot-problems-that-occur-during-boot)

Comment: This points to defective hardware, likely a bad RAM or video card. Can you try with an Ubuntu live-CD and see whether similar problems (crashes, reboots etc...) happen?

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I am a Linux user and was a bit lost here. I'll try a Linux live cd /malwares etc.

Comment: I don't know about the reboot changing settings in Safe Mode, AFAICT you can't change resolution in safe mode, and you will be prompted to reboot (not automatic).  The other symptom sounds like the refresh rate is out of range and your monitor can't sync.  If you use Safe Mode / VGA Mode to set the resolution to VGA, then reboot normally, does it help?  Also try using safe mode to uninstall the monitor and video card drivers.